# -iola as suffix

Tags: suffixes

My buddy says things like *cashiola* instead of *cash* and calls my *Mikeyola* instead of *Mikey*.  We are both native American English speakers, and my buddy swears other people say this.

Is this precendented in common English, or is he just making this up?

We have done some googling and we can’t find any words that seem to have this suffix in blogs or anything.  *Cashiola* seems to be a name.

Comment: "Cashola" without the i has a good number of legitimate Google hits.

Comment: Do you guys [talk like this](http://snltranscripts.jt.org/91/91grichmeister.phtml)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Etymonline's entry for *[pianola](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pianola&allowed_in_frame=0)* suggests:

> ca. 1896, trademark name (1901) of a player piano, the ending perhaps abstracted from viola (q.v.) and meant as a diminutive suffix.The pianola's popularity led to a rash of product names ending in -ola, especially Victrola (q.v.), and slang words such as *[payola](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=payola&searchmode=none)*.

That is, using an *-ola* suffix as a diminutive is not unprecedented, and is something that people have done for more than a century.

An anomalous example is *[granola](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=granola&searchmode=none)*, which etymonline notes was used capitalized in the years after 1886 for a kind of breakfast cereal, and has been used uncapitalized since about 1970.   1886 is ten years before the 1896-1901 timeframe mentioned earlier for popularization of the *-ola* suffix.

Comment: And let's not forget Motorola (derived in a way from a "Victrola in a motor vehicle"), which somehow has managed to survive as a name and completely overcome its 1950s early Space-Age patina.

Comment: @PaulRichter Plusola!

Answer (score 6):

There are two different *-ola* suffixes. The first one, call it [***-ola***¹](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/233331), derives from  Latin, sometimes as a dimuitive and sometimes otherwise; for example, modern Latin *hyperbola* < Greek *ὑπερβολή* is not a diminuitive, but *aureola < aureolus* and *lineola < līneola* are from  diminuitives.

About this first suffix, the *OED* says:

> classical Latin -*ola*  (in e.g. *fasciola*  (see **fasciola** *n*.), *līneola* **lineola** *n*., *sēpiola* **sepiola** n*.),* feminine singular corresponding to *-olus* **-olus** *suffix*. Compare **-olum** *suffix*.
>
> Occurring in nouns borrowed from the late 15th cent. onwards from classical and post-classical Latin, as **aureola** *n.,* **Gratiola** *n.,* **striola** *n.*
>
> Several words in *-ola*  (e.g. **cupola** *n*.) are from Italian and Spanish reflexes of Latin forms in *-ula* **-ula** *suffix*.
>
> (Not productive in English.) Occurring as a diminutive suffix in nouns.

The other version, which I’ll call [***-ola***²](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/130949), is mainly used for commercial names or in immitation thereof, and is considered chiefly U.S.    Here’s the *OED* again:

> Etymology:  Probably < *-ola*  (in **pianola** *n*.).
>
> The term **granola** *n*., apparently containing this element, appears as a trade mark in 1886 and 1928 but seems not to have been used generally until the second half of the 20th cent.
>
> One of the earliest formations with this suffix in commercial use was **Shinola** *n*.  (1903). The casual slang use is attested from 1919 onwards (see J. E. Lighter *Hist. Dict. Amer. Slang* (1997) at cited word).
>
> Chiefly *U.S.*
>
> Used to form nouns denoting commercial products (as **Editola** *n*., **moviola** *n*., **Victrola** *n*.). Subsequently (*slang*) used as a humorous device for extending ordinary words (e.g. *jazzola*); a few of these formations have become current (e.g. **boffola** *n*. and *adj*.), esp. with reference to forms of bribery (**payola** *n*., **plugola** *n*.).

Attested words ending in either of the two ***-ola*** suffixes include: *acerola, areola, aureola, barbola, cambozola, canola, carambola, choola, cola, colocola, cupola, Dongola, dongola, Ebola, Editola, española, fasciola, fasola, foveola, frottola, girandola, gola, gondola, Gorgonzola, granola, Gratiola, hemimetabola, hemiola* (now usually *hemiolia* < Latin *hēmiolia*  < Greek *ἡμιολία*), *herola, Holometabola, hordeola, hyperbola, idola, Kola, kola, lineola, lobola, mandola, Manola, mariola, massoola, mazoola, Metabola, Miliola, minneola, mobola, modiola, mola, moola, Moviola, nespola, oropendola, paleola, parabola, pascola, patola, payola, peola, pergola, Pianola, plugola, Pongola, pyrola, riffola, roseola, rubeola, Salsola, Savonarola, scagliola, schnozzola, scuola, sdrucciola, semiparabola, semola, sensoriola, sepiola, shola, sola, stola, striola, taeniola, tarentola, tetracola, tola, tombola, Tropaeola, vacciola, vandola, variola, Victrola, viola,* and *vola.*

Comment: Isn't *hemiola* an exception (i.e., not having a suffix), deriving from "... ἡμιόλιος ‘in the ratio of one and a half to one’,  ἡμι- hemi- prefix + ὅλος whole" according to the OED?

Comment: @DjinTonic And the same with hyperbola. It's hyper-bola, not hyperb-ola